# C++ Object Oriented Design frustration.

Tags: c++, oop

After working within a group project to build pretty much a copy of IRC, and manning the GUI battle station, I realise I have written code for much more than the GUI (user commands, font commands, chat filter, etc).

This being my first attempt at OOP at all, i am now stuck with a huge GUI class which i would love to split into smaller classes.

However, now I am faced with a situation like the following:

```
Class A {
public:
    int printStuff();
    int doThings();
}

A::printStuff() {
    return doThings;
}

A::doThings() {
    return 2;
}
```

A situation where the classes still need to interact. 
Keep in mind, the class system is a lot more complex than this, and there are interactions between all 5 of my proposed subclasses.

but class A should only be printing things, not doing things; as such, i would love to have it like this:

```
Class A {
public:
    int printStuff();
}

Class B {
public:
    int doThings();
}
```

What are the best/most elegant ways to go about doing so?

Heres the actual chunk from the header, if it helps; I've commented in the functions/variables each method requires- and also outlined my proposed subclasses:

```
// ncurses (GUI, screens)
void setup();           // initScreen(); initWindows();
void initScreen();      // ncurses.h
void initWindows();     // screen vars, ncruses.h,          dummy text
void resize();          // screen vars, ncruses.h, showScreen();
void Routine();         

// message factory (GUI, controll, vars)
string mRequested();                            // _messageQueue
void mRecieved(string message);                 // command(), printchat(), _chatlog, _user
bool command(string message, int out_in);       // _user, _messageQueue, mRecieved -- quit(not made), removeUser
int checkVulgar(string *message);               // _user
string upperCase(string message);               

// GUI (windows, vars)
void printAscii(WINDOW *scr, char *gaphics[], int sizey, int sizex, int starty, int startx);                                        // ncurses.h, windows
void printServers(WINDOW *scr, int a);                                                                                              // ncurses.h, windows
void printMessage(string message, int message_lines, int *h_index, int *attempt, int *message_len, int prev_len, int endline);      // ncurses.h, windows
void printUsers(WINDOW *scr);                                                                                                       // _users, ncurses.h, windows
void printTimeout();
void printChat();                                                                                                                   // printMessage(), fontcommands, _chatlog, ncurses.h, windows                                                                                                   // 
void showScreen(int a, int b);                                                                                                      // printAscii,servers,users,chat , ncurses.h, windows


// control (GUI, _users)
void updateUsers(vector<User> users);   // _users, printUsers();
void removeUser(string user);           // _users, printUsers();

// Boundary (ncurses, GUI, messageFactory, vars)
void userInput();       
void userInputB();      // _user, resize(), printchat(), mRecieved(), checkvulgar(), quit(), command(), _messageQueue
int selectServer();     // showScreen()
```

Comment: Since you're talking about subclasses, is `B` supposed to inherit class `A` in your _real_ code? If yes, are you sure that `B` really is an `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reworking the class design and starting from scratch, I've managed to separate and reuse most of my earlier code.

For anyone wondering, the mainApp now talks directly to the MessageFactory; MF contains an object of both GUI and Windows (ncurses in previous image).

This is really how it should have been from the beginning, and poor planning (due to not knowing anything about command line GUI, and the excitement of adding new features) has caused me a great deal of grief.

Plan properly, or suffer.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the best/most elegant ways to go about doing so?

Sit down on a sofa for a few days and come up with a robust and elegant design.

Then implement that design.

The mistake you made was not designing *before* you began coding. Now it's already time to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what classes should do what, try and make some CRC cards. They are a great help to figure out what the class diagram should look like.